# Finding records when using has_many through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, Worker and Project, and they are connected with has_many through association.

I manage to find all the projects which are related to a specific worker by writing the following code:

```
worker=Worker.find_by_id("some_id") 
worker.projects
```

but I want the projects that I get to be only active projects (in the project model I have a status field)

I tried to do something like

```
worker.projects(:status_id=>'active')
```

but it didn’t work for me.

Can somebody tell me how I can do this?

Comment: @piemesons: I can imagine that this particular point of syntax would be difficult to just plain look up in the documentation where necessary. The difficulty is only compounded by the fact that the relationship makes use of duck typing, making it almost surprising that the `#all` method exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
worker.projects.all(:conditions => {:status_id => 'active'})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
worker.projects.all(:conditions => {:status_id => 'active'})
```

will work. (answer edited after the comment)

Comment: They do, in fact, behave differently, though. `#find` throws an exception on failure, whereas `#find_by_id` returns nil on failure.